# Excel - How can I use a Start and End date to format cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a calendar and a table of events on a worksheet.  The table of events include a Start and End date as well as Status columns.  I would like to highlight the dates on the calendar where the event(s) are approved.

Here is how the worksheet is setup:
- Top left cell of the calendar is B9.
- The name of the table with the events is "Events".
- The range of the "Events" table is `Z8:AE44` (I could not find a way to use the table in a the vlookup function).
- The first column of the Events table is "Start".
- The second column is "End".
- The Sixth column is "Status", which is set to "Approved".

I have used the formula below in a Conditional Formatting rule.  This works well for single day events or if you add an entry for every day of the event in the events table.  I would like to be able use the end date so there doesn't have to be multiple entries for events that are more than one day.

```
=IF(LEN(B9)=0, FALSE, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9, $Z$8:$AE$44, 6, FALSE), FALSE)="Approved")
```

[Click Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4_6YtrlDxt4c0ZGdGVFaUE2S2c/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel) is a link to a sample worksheet.

Comment: your question isn't really clear now. Could you please post also some sample data with desired output?

Comment: I have added a link to the worksheet to help ... I want to use the event start and end dates to highlight the appropriate cells in the calendar